# What is the time complexity of the following codes in Big O notation?

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

1. `T(n) = 8*T(n/2) + n*n`
2. `T(n) = 3*T(n/4) + n`

I want to calculate the time complexity in Big O notation . What is the answer (without using master theorem)

Comment: the answer is to apply the master theorem

Comment: Can you please explain How master theorem works?

Comment: Does any one know why I got 4 down-votes for adding this question?

Comment: Because you didn't bother just googling "master theorem", but instead just wanted other people to do your work for you. StackOverflow is intended to help people answer questions that they can't easily answer on their own.

Comment: I was unable to understand master theorem by looking at it on Wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The master theorem applies to any recurrence of the form `T(n) = a*T(n/b) + n^c`. It looks at and compares the two parts of the recurrence:

1) The size of the constant work at this level (c)
2) The number and size of the recursive calls (a and b)

From here, We compare log_b (a) to c. There are three possibilities

1. `log_b (a) > c` -> `T(n)` is `O(n^log_b (a))`
2. `log_b (a) < c` -> `T(n)` is `O(n^c)`
3. `log_b (a) = c` -> `T(n)` is `O(n^c log(n))`

So for your two examples...

1. `T(n) = 8*T(n/2) + n*n`, therefore `a = 8, b = 2, c = 2`, `log_2 (8) > 2`, therefore `T(n)` is `O(n^(log_2 (8))` = `O(n^3)`
2. `T(n) = 3 * T(n/4) + n`, therefore `a = 3, b = 4, c = 1`, `log_4 (3) < 1`, therefore `T(n)` is `O(n^c)` = `O(n)`

[A fuller explanation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

For the first relation, you can do this:

[image]